# Complex queries to MS SQL Server

Tags: databaselink

I'm using DatabaseLink to query MS SQL Server with SQLExecute which works totaly fine, for ex.:

```
SQLExecute[conn, "declare @dt date;
select * from ttable where date=@dt"]
```

However the problem starts when i try to use table variable and try to return it, for ex.:

```
SQLExecute[conn, "declare @dt date;
declare @tab table(
var1 int
date date)
insert into @tab
select * from ttable where date=@dt;
select * from @tab"]
```

It returns the number of rows and not the table. Is there a way to solve that?
It seems that Mathematica returns results for the 'insert' statement, not the final results.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

By default, SQL Server will return two result sets when it executes the exhibited SQL batch.  The first result set contains the number of rows inserted by the `INSERT` statement.  The second contains the rows from the `SELECT` statement.  DatabaseLink will only report the first result set from a batch.  However, you can tell SQL Server to avoid generating the first result set by adding the command `SET NOCOUNT ON` prior to the `INSERT` statement.